# converting -TSQL statement "DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()))" to C#

Tags: t-sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

how can i convert this T-SQL query `DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE()))` to C#?

Comment: The SQL removes the time part from the date and give you todays date at midnight. I.e `2013-02-15 00:00:00`. In C# that would be `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That T-SQL returns the today date at 12.00 AM.  (Where [12:00AM is considered midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight))
Thus a very simple equivalent of that is

```
 DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Today;
 Console.WriteLine(todayDate.ToString());
```

Comment: You should not add 12 hours. `DateTime.Today` is the answer to the question.

Comment: 12:00 AM is 00:00 (or 24:00 if you wish). 12:00 PM is 12:00.

Answer (score -1):

you can use AddDays which can add-days or subtract days

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddDays(+1);
```

Comment: Although your statement is true, it does not answer the question. -1

Comment: Its not the current date he want to get, OP want to add or subtract something from that too, though he has kept '0'...but actually he also want to know the replacement for DateDiff and DateAdd functions...

Comment: No, I dont think that it is the case. As that SQL sequence is very common, for removing the time dart of the date. A correct translation to C# would be `DateTime.MinValue.AddDays((DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue).Days)`. But that would just give you the same date as `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: So are you saying that correct answer would be just DateTime date=DateTime.Today;
In that case i would say, in question he just would have asked for 'getting date without time part'

Comment: Indeed, but maybe OP didnt know how the SQL worked. Just that now was the time to move this functionality to the application.